# Allowing up to 2 consecutive line breaks in HTML

Tags: php, regex

For example:

```
StackOverflow<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
is
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
a
<br>
community.
```

To:

```
StackOverflow
<br>
<br>
is
<br>
<br>
a
<br>
community.
```

If there are more than 2 `<br>` in a string, it should delete all the `<br>` and keep only two.
Code so far:

```
$txt_unclean = trim(nl2br($_POST['txt_content']));
$txt_content = strip_tags($txt_unclean, '<br>');
```

What is the next step? How do I allow no more than 2 `<br>`.

Comment: Don't use regex. Use a real HTML parser.

Comment: A DOM parser seems the route to take here.

Comment: @MattBall That's actually not so easy as it sounds for this particular case; though, it should be said that I didn't realize HTML manipulation could actually be avoided in this case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code [`in action`](http://ideone.com/KtQGpe):

```
<?php
$str = <<<STR
StackOverflow<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
is
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
a
<br>
community.
STR;
echo preg_replace("!(<br(?:\s?/)?>\s*){2,}!s", "<br />\n<br />\n", $str);
```

Comment: As we can clearly say this question is neither right nor wrong. Meaning: It may suit you well and you might fail well with it. Is this a programming answer? Ask yourself.

Comment: @hakre to be, or not to be: that is the question ;) Ask yourself.

Answer (score 6):

If your mark-up is controlled like that, you could use `preg_replace` to match more than two consecutive `<br>`:

```
$txt_content = preg_replace('/(<br>\s*){3,}/', '$1$1', $txt_content);
```

To also match self-closing tags:

```
$txt_content = preg_replace('/(<br\s*/>\s*){3,}/', '$1$1', $txt_content);
```

Otherwise, I would consider using a DOM parser to do this work; having said that, it's not as easy :)

Comment: I think you mean short open tags,. Short open tags on their end won't be `[^>]*>` alone, so this comes close. But you also might fail well with this. A HTML parser would be a straight forward solution and if not, this still needs parsing. So not possible with a singular expression.

Comment: @hakre I'm assuming here that the HTML is already valid, in which case `[^>]*>` is appropriate :)

Comment: `>` is no-saying in X(HT)ML. `<` is the character that sign on things. Theee tags.

Comment: Technically (read: nit-picking but there is some truth), short-open tags end with `/>` not (not `>`) `>`. Therefore better keep it correct (yes, this is hard to achieve, we only get this right if we really need to, and the solutions which should be answers are hard to find).

Answer (score 4):

Since you have access to the string before newlines are converted into `<br>`s, this is how I'd do it:

```
<?php
$string = <<<END
1
2


3




4




5
END;
$string = trim(nl2br(preg_replace('/(\r?\n){3,}/', '$1$1', $string)));
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
1<br />
2<br />
<br />
3<br />
<br />
4<br />
<br />
5
```

[**[Demo]**](http://viper-7.com/RPeQyA)

Comment: +1 Didn't think of that :) Though `preg_replace('/(\r?\n){3,}/', '$1$1', $string);` would be easier imho.

Comment: Thanks @Jack - I knew there would be a shorter way :-)